# TEXT Query in Apache Ignite not giving any result

Tags: lucene, ignite

Following are the items that I did

- I started the ignite in remote mode.
- I created a cache and added some data. (Also created the cache configuration)
- I am doing the text query.

My code looks like this

```
TcpDiscoverySpi spi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();

    TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder(true);
    String hosts[] = new String[]{"ip:48500"} ;
    ipFinder.setAddresses(Arrays.asList(hosts));
    /**
     *  create a new instance of tcp discovery multicast ip finder TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder tcMp = new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();
     *
     **tcMp.setAddresses(Arrays.asList("localhost")); // change your IP address here // set the multi cast ip finder for spi
     */




    spi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);
    /**
     *  create new ignite configuration
     */
    IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration(); 
    cfg.setClientMode(true);
    cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);
    /**
     * CacheConfiguration cacheConfig = cacheConfigure();
     * cfg.setCacheConfiguration(cacheConfig);
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    CacheConfiguration cacheConfig = cacheConfigure();
    cfg.setCacheConfiguration(cacheConfig);
    /**
     *  set the discovery spi to ignite configuration 
     */
    cfg.setDiscoverySpi(spi);
    /**
     *  Start ignite
     */
    Ignite ignite = Ignition.getOrStart(cfg);
```

and my cache configuration is

```
    CacheConfiguration ccfg = new CacheConfiguration(DEFAULT_CACHE_NAME);



    QueryEntity queryEntity = new QueryEntity();
    queryEntity.setKeyType(Integer.class.getName());
    queryEntity.setValueType(Account.class.getName());
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> fields = new LinkedHashMap();

    fields.put("accid", Integer.class.getName());
    fields.put("attrbool", Boolean.class.getName());
    fields.put("accbalance", BigDecimal.class.getName());
    fields.put("acctype", String.class.getName());
    fields.put("attrbyte", Byte.class.getName());
    fields.put("accifsc", String.class.getName());

    queryEntity.setFields(fields);


 // Listing indexes.
    Collection<QueryIndex> indexes = new ArrayList<>(3);

     indexes.add(new QueryIndex("accid"));
     indexes.add(new QueryIndex("accifsc"));
     indexes.add(new QueryIndex("acctype"));

     queryEntity.setIndexes(indexes);

     ccfg.setQueryEntities(Arrays.asList(queryEntity));
```

and I am putting data to cache

```
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {

    Account account=new Account();

    account.setAccid(1234+i);

    account.setAttrbool(true);

    account.setAccbalance(new BigDecimal(100000+i));

    account.setAcctype("Demat");

    account.setAttrbyte(new Byte("1"));

    account.setAccifsc("Master Degree Pstgraduate");

    cache.put(new Integer(i), account);

    }
```

and now doing the text query

```
     TextQuery txt = new TextQuery(Account.class,"IFC" );

    try (@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    QueryCursor<Entry<Integer, Account>> masters = cache.query(txt)) {

          for (Entry<Integer, Account> e : masters)

            System.out.println("results "+e.getValue().toString());
        }
```

My Data Class is

```
public class Account {

//primary key
@QueryTextField
private Integer accid ;
@QueryTextField
private BigDecimal accbalance ;

@QueryTextField@QuerySqlField 
private String accifsc ;

private BigInteger accnum ;

private String accstr ;
@QueryTextField
private String acctype ;

@QueryTextField
private Boolean attrbool ;
@QueryTextField
private Byte attrbyte ;

// getter and setter

 }
```

What am I doing wrong? There is no error in the log.

Comment: Did you annotate your text fields with `@QueryTextField`?

Comment: yes. I have updated the question.

Comment: And what's inside createAcc? How do you know there should be results?

Comment: After putting the data to cache, I tried getting it and I got my data back. I will include that part also in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the Text query code part a bit and it worked for me

```
    TextQuery txt = new TextQuery(Account.class,"IFC" );

    try (@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    QueryCursor masters = cache.query(txt)) {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<CacheEntryImpl<Integer,Account>> accounts = masters.getAll();
        Iterator<CacheEntryImpl<Integer, Account>> iterator = accounts.iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()) {

                System.out.println(iterator.next().getValue().getAccifsc());

            }

        }
```